# Sort Schedule Order by Week Day (e.g Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to solve a problem on my code. I have a hardcoded state data let's say it's from an API call. The API data for operationHours is not ordered properly by default in my case the thursday gets first instead of monday. My problem is I want to sort them by day of week (monday, tuesday, wednesday, ...) whenever I map the data. I made a sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-booth-4gwfi

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      name: "Starbucks",
      operationHours: {
        thursday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        friday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        saturday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        sunday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        monday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" },
        wednesday: { from: "8:00", to: "20:00" }
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.data.name}</h2>
        {Object.keys(this.state.data.operationHours).map(dayOfWeek => (
          <div key={dayOfWeek} className="day-of-week">
            {`${dayOfWeek} - ${moment(
              this.state.data.operationHours[dayOfWeek].from,
              "HH:mm"
            ).format("hh:mm A")} -
            ${moment(
              this.state.data.operationHours[dayOfWeek].to,
              "HH:mm"
            ).format("hh:mm A")}`}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by sorting them, you want the returned data to start with Monday, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
{Object.keys(this.state.data.operationHours).map(dayOfWeek => (
      <div key={dayOfWeek} className="day-of-week">
```

take an array with the sorted days, like

```
{['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday'].map(dayOfWeek => (
      <div key={dayOfWeek} className="day-of-week">
```